# What's the an efficient way to sort a large list of numbers without being able to consistently compare them?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I know the title is vague but I don't know the terminology required to make it clearer. I'm very bad at math, but this problem has been rattling around in my head all day, and I was wondering if there's any simple solution to it.

Let's say I have 100 paintings I want to display in my art museum, and I want to sort them from best to worst. For the purposes of this hypothetical, we'll say each painting has a number *Q* between 0 and 1 representing its quality (although we don't know what this number is).

We also have an intern. He can compare two paintings, and say which he thinks is better. However, this is a subjective rating, so he has a chance of being wrong. His odds of being correct are $abs(Q_1 - Q_2) * .5 + .5$. So for two paintings very close to each other in quality, he'll have about a 50% chance of being right, but with one painting with a *Q* close to 1 and another with a *Q* close to 0, he'll be right almost all the time. (asking the intern to compare the same two paintings multiple times may result in different outputs)

The paintings' *Q* values have a normal distribution.

Extra credit: you've sorted the 100 paintings. You look through your attic and find another you forgot about. What's the most efficient way to insert it into the list?

Note that I'm not necessarily looking for the *most* efficient way, I just don't want our poor intern to spend too much time comparing paintings, so we would prefer if he has to compare each painting as few times as possible for a reasonable level of certainty in our sorting

Thanks for your help!

[Hopefully helpful diagram!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL4IY.png)

Comment: Values between $0$ and $1$ can't have a normal distribution. And how do you define "efficient"? How are your probabilities entering that definition?

Comment: You're right, not a normal distribution. I'm not sure what the correct term is but I'm thinking of something like a bell curve.

I'm asking if there's an algorithm to decide which paintings to show to the intern, and how to sort them based on his responses, given a certain number of comparisons per painting. I would say the efficiency of the algorithm would be having the greatest certainty in the sorting of the paintings for the same number of comparisons, or having the same or greater certainty with fewer comparisons. I'm sorry if this doesn't make any sense

Comment: this sounds a bit like a sports tournament: when two teams play, the better team has a greater chance of winning, but it doesn't always. So borrowing from that analogy, the most thorough approach is the round-robin scheme, where every two teams play against each other a certain number of times, but indeed that is not very efficient. The fastest is direct elimination (like most tennis tournaments, for example), but this will be very unreliable. What you want is perhaps what is commonly done in chess tournaments, the so-called swiss system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss-system_tournament